# Prevent buffer overflows with gets

Tags: c, language-lawyer, fgets, buffer-overflow, gets

The declaration of `gets` is:

```
char * gets ( char * str );
```

Note the **glaring omission** of a maximum size for *str*.

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com) says<sup>[2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)</sup>:

> Notice that gets is quite different from fgets: not only gets uses
>   stdin as source, but it does not include the ending newline character
>   in the resulting string and does not allow to specify a maximum size
>   for str (**which can lead to buffer overflows**).

And also:

> The most recent revision of the C standard (2011) has definitively
>   removed this function from its specification. The function is
>   deprecated in C++ (as of 2011 standard, which follows C99+TC3).

Now, of course, `fgets` is commonly recommended as a replacement of `gets`, because its declaration looks like this:

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

It **DOES** take a size parameter. This makes it much safer than `gets`.

Now since I'm not willing to shell out money to download or buy the `C11 standard`, can anyone shed some light on the reason for deprecating `gets` and what it means for future code? Why did it exist in the same place when `fgets` is safer? And why is it **only just now** being deprecated?

Comment: The [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is nearly identical to the released ISO C11 standard.

Comment: I don't think this question is primarily opinion based because there is an explanation by the C committee for why `gets` was in the standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gets` is deprecated because it's unsafe, as what you already quoted, it may cause buffer overflow. For replacement, C11 provides an alternative `gets_s` with a signature like this:

```
char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);
```

Note that C11 still recommends `fgets` to replace `gets`.

Whether putting `gets` in the standard is controversial in the first place, but the Committee decided that `gets` was useful when the programmer does have adequate control over the input.

Here's the official explanation by the Committee.

> #### [Rationale for International Standard - Programming Languages C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) §7.19.7.7 *The `gets` function*:
>
> Because `gets` does not check for buffer overrun, it is generally unsafe to use when its input is not under the programmer’s control. This has caused some to question whether it should appear in the Standard at all. The Committee decided that `gets` was useful and convenient in those special circumstances when the programmer does have adequate control over the input, and as longstanding existing practice, it needed a standard specification. In general, however, the preferred function is `fgets` (see §7.19.7.2).

Comment: `gets_s` is not widely available (and that's an understatement). AFAIK the only place where it is available is Windows.

Answer (score 2):

*Now since I'm not willing to shell out money to download or buy the C11 standard, can anyone shed some light on the reason for deprecating gets and what it means for future code?*

From C committee in C99 Rationale:

> Because gets does not check for buffer overrun, it is generally unsafe to use when its input is not under the programmer’s control. This has caused some to question whether it should appear in the Standard at all. The Committee decided that gets was useful and convenient in those special circumstances when the programmer does have adequate control over the input, and as longstanding existing practice, it needed a standard specification. In general, however, the
>   preferred function is fgets.

Comment: n1570's the latest draft; Google it and you should be able to find a (legal) download.